# How can I have devise return JSON to me in ajax:success call instead of HTML

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, devise

I am trying to set up my devise registration as an ajax call, so that I can get the errors in my user sign up flow.  Currently, I have it so that it is able to create a user on success, but I am unable to get the errors in JSON form to use properly to make validations for the user.

Here is what I have right now:

**form**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), format: :json, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :card_id %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**js**

```
$('#new_user').on("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

In this case, status responds with the HTML that would normally occur on a standard devise add on

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `Devise::RegistrationsController` and create your own controller actions if you want to return JSON data. Just structure it like you would a normal create action. Then use `render json` if you want to return data to the client. [Devise's Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) should provide plenty of help and there's lots of other resources around the web too.